# In editor window script in unity , when I disable the horizontal scroll view bar it's still affecting the textfield. How to disable it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using static Unity.VisualScripting.Member;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using log4net.Util;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameObjectAndScriptName
{
    public GameObject GameObject;
    public string ScriptName;

    public GameObjectAndScriptName(GameObject gameObject, string scriptName)
    {
        GameObject = gameObject;
        ScriptName = scriptName;
    }
}

public class ScriptFinder : EditorWindow
{
    static ScriptFinder window;
    static List<GameObjectAndScriptName> gameObjectAndScriptNames = new List<GameObjectAndScriptName>();
    Vector2 scrollPos;
    static List<int> num = new List<int>();
    static List<string> test = new List<string>();

    [MenuItem("EditorUtility/Script Finder")]
    static void OpenScriptFinder()
    {
        window = (ScriptFinder)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ScriptFinder),false,"Script Finder");
        window.minSize = new Vector2(700, 700);
        window.maxSize = new Vector2(700, 700);
        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
        foreach (MonoBehaviour script in scripts)
        {
            Type scriptType = script.GetType();
            var scope = scriptType.Namespace;

            if (scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))
            {
                if (!gameObjectAndScriptNames.Any(x => x.GameObject == script.gameObject))
                {
                    gameObjectAndScriptNames.Add(new GameObjectAndScriptName(script.gameObject, scriptType.Name));
                }
            }
        }

        Traverse();
    }

    static void Traverse()
    {
        foreach (UnityEngine.Transform t in UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(UnityEngine.Transform)))
        {
            test.Add(t.name);
            Debug.Log(t.name);
        }
    }

    string searchString;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        GUI.color = Color.white;
        GUILayout.Space(30);
        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUIStyle.none, GUI.skin.verticalScrollbar);
        searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachTextField"));

        if (GUILayout.Button("", GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachCancelButton")))
        {
            searchString = "";
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(15);

        GUIStyle TextFieldStyles = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.textField);
        GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
        GUI.color = Color.white;

        //Value Color
        TextFieldStyles.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        //Label Color
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("         Overall number of GameObjects in Hierarchy: " + test.Count.ToString());
        EditorGUILayout.Space(10);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("         GameObject                                                                                 Script");
        GUILayout.Space(5);
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        foreach (GameObjectAndScriptName item in gameObjectAndScriptNames)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                if (item.ScriptName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 25;
                    EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(), item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true);
                    counter++;

                    foreach (UnityEngine.Transform g in item.GameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<UnityEngine.Transform>())
                    {
                    }
                    num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 25;
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(), item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true);

                num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
                if (counter != gameObjectAndScriptNames.Count)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }

        GUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
}
```

On this line I'm using the scrollview and disable the horizontal one.

```
scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUIStyle.none, GUI.skin.verticalScrollbar);
```

but it's just hiding it and not really disabling it.

This screenshot is showing the editor window when the textfield is empty the row script all the items directly under the script in yellow:

[only vertical scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WO0l.jpg)

but once I type something in the textField and have a result now the item/s under the yellow Script are not directly under it because the horizontal scroll bar is up now.  you can't see it but it exist and making the items to change the position a bit.

How can I avoid it and keep the items to be directly under the yellow script ?

I'm typing G in the textfield search field and the items under Script moved a bit to the left:

[items now moved a bit to the left under the yellow Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLpMN.jpg)

but if for example I type C letter and there are much more items then they are kept being under the yellow Script directly. so I'm not sure if the problem is with the horizontal scroll view bar or something else.

[items directly under the yellow Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7i4z.jpg)

I tried anything I can think of. tried looking in google.